# Working of SizeOf Function for char Array

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

```
void main()
{
   char s[]="\12345s\n";
   printf("%d",sizeof(s));
}
```

When i compile it it giving 6. I am not geting why it is giving 6 insted of 8.
  Like `{'\1','2','3','4','5','s','\n'}`

Please can anybody tell the reason for this, I want some deep and clear explanation. I will be thankful to them.

Comment: Try printing `s` and you should then see what is going on.

Comment: You have UB in the `printf` call: the format specifies an `int` but the `sizeof` supplies a `size_t`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sizeof arrays and pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672162/sizeof-arrays-and-pointers)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `\123` is considered one character, it's an escape sequence (octal). So `sizeof` calculates 5 characters `'\123'`, `'4'`, `'5'`, `'s'`, `'\n'`,  and the ending `'\0'`.

Comment: won't this give 4 anyway its considered a pointer no matter what the string is?

Comment: @Dineshkumar there is a difference between char* and char[], here `s` is an array so the `sizeof` returns the size of the array. in cases where the arrays decays into a pointer e.g. passed to a function `foo(char*p)` `sizeof` will return 4 (or whatever size a pointer normally has - depends on OS)

Answer (score 2):

```
char s[]="\12345s\n";
```

`\` indicates escape sequence
It is octal by default if numbers are used upto 3 places.
So \123 will be evaluated in octal as 
-> 8*8*1 + 8*2 + 3 = 83
So if you print this you would find it
S45s
As S -> Ascii equivalent of 83 
Hence the size is also 4.

Answer (score 1):

```
char s[]="\12345s\n"
```

is equal to:

```
char s[] = { '\123', '4', '5', 's', '\n', 0 }
```

so six elements in total.

Comment: elmo That's what i am asking why it is considering like { '\123', '4', '5', 's', '\n', 0 } why not {'\1','2','3','4','5','s','\n'}

Comment: @Nishant: If you want to have "\12" to be recognised as {'\1','2'} you need to enter "\0012".

Comment: @Nishant because otherwise you wouldn't be able to specify anything with more than one digit after backslash.
As alk said is the way to go. If it did take \123 as \1, 2 and 3 how would you specify actually \123?