# sizeof operator returns different values when array is assigned to a pointer. Why?

Tags: c, sizeof

**Sample code :**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int arr[5] = {10,20,30,40,50};
        int *p;
        p = arr;
        printf("Total size calculating from array = %ld\n", sizeof(arr));
        printf("Total size calculating from pointer = %ld \n",sizeof(p));
        return 0;
}
```

**Output :**

```
Total size calculating from array = 20
Total size calculating from pointer = 8
```

My understanding so far was that you can assign the address of the array to a pointer of same data type and do all the operations on it without any problem. But `sizeof` is returning different values.

So i have few questions here :

- Is assigning good practice or not?
- What things gets changed when we assign?
- why 8?

Comment: Depends on what you consider to be a "problem".

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672162/sizeof-arrays-and-pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is assigning good practice or not?

Yes, for example if you pass an array to a function it will decay into a pointer. Let's say you need to keep the original pointer but you also need another one to iterate through the array. You declare a separate pointer that points to the same address and use that to iterate through it.

> What things gets changed when we assign?

The pointer points to an address, that's it (previously it could have pointed to another address or NULL), the assignee (in your case the array) is not modified. There is a big difference between an array and a pointer which is why you get different results for it. Pointers and arrays are only seemingly equivalent.

You can still use the pointer to access and modify the contents of the array, but the two are not the same (as illustrated by the result of `sizeof`).

> why 8?

On 32 bit machines a pointer is normally 4 bytes big, on 64 it is 8. If you take the size of a local array, the `sizeof` will multiply the number of elements in the array by how big each element is. Five integers each four bytes big equals 20.

Answer (score 1):

array size denotes the total size of the array which in this case are 5 integers. But a pointer to the array actually stores a memory address whose size depends on the system you are using. So they are different

Answer (score 0):

> why 8?

`sizeof` operator gives total byte size for `statically` defined array while for pointers it gives `pointer` size which can be 8 bytes for 64 bit systems and 4 bytes for 32 bit systems.

> Is assigning good practice or not?

Yes, because in C you do not have much choice but a better way is using [references](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html) in C++.

> What things gets changed when we assign?

Nothing changes, original data is preserved.

Comment: No references in C I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(arr)` is giving size of array which is 20 Bytes in your case.When you perform `p = arr;` it is actually assigning address of first array element(&arr[0]) to integer pointer `p`.So now sizeof(p) is giving size of integer pointer only.

Remember array and pointer are not same.Array name is address of its first element.An array may decay as pointer.