# accurate display of size of an 1D array

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic

I have a problem in displaying the size of the array correctly.
I know array size is 256000 but it is displaying as 8 when I enter the loop. size will be displayed accurately if dynamic allocation is not used. How do I rectify the bug using dynamic allocation?

Comment: Are you maybe measuring the size of the pointer pointing to the array?

Comment: no. Size of the array

Comment: It's pretty damn hard to fix a bug without the code that's causing it.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sizeof arrays and pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672162/sizeof-arrays-and-pointers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you size 10, because the compiler knows it's an array;

```
char foo[10];
int size = sizeof foo;
```

This will give you size 4 on a 32-bit architecture, because it's the size of a pointer.

```
char *foo = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
int size = sizeof foo;
```

After this, the usage of `foo` is identical. You can do `foo[2]` or `*foo` or whatever with both versions. But you probably shouldn't take the address of `&foo` with the 1st variant. And you should `free(foo);` sometimes with the 2nd.

Always remember: sizeof is not a function, sizeof is always decided in compile time.

Comment: Also: function arguments are pointers, not arrays, so this one is also a pointer: `void f(char foo[10]);`.

Comment: oh that was useful!! but how do I get size as 10 itself using malloc?

Comment: The simple answer: you don't.

Comment: then any other method to know the size?

Comment: Hint: when you `malloc(x)` you have to know the size `x`. Store that in a variable. That's the size.